# How do I remove or disable Adobe Registration request and kill Adobe IPC, Adobecloud

Tags: terminal, adobe

I found this on the registration, but where and how to put this into:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Determine OS version
osvers=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F. '{print $2}')
sw_vers=$(sw_vers -productVersion)

# Checks first to see if the Mac is running 10.7.0 or higher. 
# If so, the script checks the system default user template
# for the presence of the Library/Preferences directory.
#
# If the directory is not found, it is created and then the
# iCloud pop-up settings are set to be disabled.

if [[ ${osvers} -ge 7 ]]; then

 for USER_TEMPLATE in "/System/Library/User Template"/*
  do
    defaults write "${USER_TEMPLATE}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE
    defaults write "${USER_TEMPLATE}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant GestureMovieSeen none
    defaults write "${USER_TEMPLATE}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant LastSeenCloudProductVersion "${sw_vers}"
  done

 # Checks first to see if the Mac is running 10.7.0 or higher.
 # If so, the script checks the existing user folders in /Users
 # for the presence of the Library/Preferences directory.
 #
 # If the directory is not found, it is created and then the
 # iCloud pop-up settings are set to be disabled.

 for USER_HOME in /Users/*
  do
    USER_UID=`basename "${USER_HOME}"`
    if [ ! "${USER_UID}" = "Shared" ] 
    then 
      if [ ! -d "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences ]
      then
        mkdir -p "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences
      fi
      if [ -d "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences ]
      then
        defaults write "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE
        defaults write "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant GestureMovieSeen none
        defaults write "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant LastSeenCloudProductVersion "${sw_vers}"
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
      fi
    fi
  done
fi
```

Also I found this, but I copied that in my terminal and nothing happened. What do I need to do excatly?

this is a terminal alias/command I use that prevents any Adobe stuff running in the background:

> alias nothankyouadobe="sudo -H killall ACCFinderSync \"Core Sync\" AdobeCRDaemon \"Adobe Creative\" AdobeIPCBroker node \"Adobe Desktop Service\" \"Adobe Crash Reporter\";sudo -H rm -rf \"/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist\" \"/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist\" \"/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.*.plist\""

If you put that in your ~/.bash_profile you can then simply type nothankyouadobe or call that from Alfred or any other sort of script.

Comment: Where did you get the script?  It’s not doing anything with respect to Adobe.

Comment: I got that from here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204315/how-do-i-remove-or-disable-adobeipcbroker?newreg=6494d23c4b694caa81331075d05677ba

Comment: So Allan, what would help?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling it first?

Answer (score 5):

I made an updated version of the script that also removes the associated launchd services and uses the `pluginkit` utility to disable the Core Sync Finder Extension, as explained [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237585/366438) but programmatically

```
#!/bin/bash

# ask root password
sudo echo -n

echo "Deactivating Core Sync Finder extension"
pluginkit -e ignore -i com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync
# uncomment to completely remove the extension 
# pluginkit -r "/Applications/Utilities/Adobe Sync/CoreSync/Core Sync.app/Contents/PlugIns/ACCFinderSync.appex"

echo "Removing plist files"
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.*.plist
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.*.plist
rm -f ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.*.plist

for SERVICE in $(launchctl list | grep "com.adobe" | cut -f3)
do
    echo "Removing service ${SERVICE}"
    launchctl remove $SERVICE
done

# Add processes to this list if needed,
# sometimes their name might change or there might be others,
# depending on wich adobe product was used. 
# You can use the Activity monitor app to check for potential rogue processes
PROCESSES=(
"ACCFinderSync"
"CoreSync"
"Core Sync"
"Creative Cloud Helper"
"Core Sync Helper"
"AdobeCRDaemon"
"Adobe Creative"
"AdobeIPCBroker"
"Adobe Desktop Service"
"Adobe Crash Reporter"
)

for p in "${PROCESSES[@]}"
do
    echo "Killing process ${p}"
    sudo -H killall "${p}" 2> /dev/null
done
```

You can save this script into a file called "adobye" for exemple, and execute `chmod +x adobye && mv adobye /usr/local/bin`, to turn it into a globally available command. You can then simply type `adobye` in terminal whenever you want to remove adobe processes

Comment: I am so going to use this script. Thank you so much for “adobye”!

Answer (score 1):

## Do NOT execute unknown scripts or executables.

What you got is a script. But in this case, it doesn't seem helpful for any Adobe process, so jump to alias section.

> `#!/bin/sh`

indicates that is uses `sh` to process the upcoming commands. You should:

- Open TextEdit.app, paste the script there.
- Save it as `AdobeScript.sh`. Notice the `.sh` extension. Name can be anything.
- Open terminal, type `sh`, space  & the path to the script, in double quotes.

  ```
  sh "/Users/yourUserName/Desktop/AdobeScript.sh"
  ```

  And hit enter. It will execute.

As for the alias, see these answers to see how they work:

- [Use Automator to open app as itself?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392216/use-automator-to-open-app-as-itself/392222#392222)
- for GUI method: [How to add the PATH for mysql bin on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371614/how-to-add-the-path-for-mysql-bin-on-mac/371665#371665)

The alias is equivalent to executing these commands individually. So you can also use Activity Monitor to kill the processes & go to the filepaths to delete the files/folders manually.

```
sudo -H killall ACCFinderSync
sudo -H killall \"Core Sync\"
sudo -H killall AdobeCRDaemon
sudo -H killall \"Adobe Creative\"
sudo -H killall AdobeIPCBroker node
sudo -H killall \"Adobe Desktop Service\"
sudo -H killall \"Adobe Crash Reporter\"

sudo -H rm -rf "/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist"
sudo -H rm -rf "/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist"
sudo -H rm -rf "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.*.plist"
```

Comment: Hi Ankii! Thanks. Did you know what scrip is doing, I mean is that the right one, for the purpose. I don't understand this language.

Comment: I tried. But it says: No such file or directory ( Terminal). I past the script in a text called it AdobeScript.sh (It saved as RTF) and then opened Terminal.

Comment: oke. I exchanged "you" to my name. Now it says: Permission denied

Comment: @marcelllolluke make sure the extension is `.sh` nothing else after it. 
also, you **shouldn't** execute scripts you don't know. also, see updated answer

Comment: Had look at the Alias solution, but I have no idea how to apply this for the adobe. I am bloody beginner if comes to all this here.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should not use this script? Cause I really do know what is does, only relying on the recommendation from community.

Comment: @marcelllolluke AFAIK, that script will not help you here. It is executing commands like `defaults write "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE` which seems ... _useless_ to me .

Comment: @marcelllolluke for the alias answer, where are you stuck ? did you see the GUI method ?

Comment: @marcelllolluke that alias is equivalent to executing these commands one by one: https://pastebin.com/kQ9W2jBA