# How to disable apps from auto launch if I have already disabled them?

Tags: macos, mac

When I turn my Mac on, Messages, Mail and Creative Cloud are opened automatically on the main screen. It looks like this:

[image]

It eally annoys!

I have checked my login items and there are not such apps.

[image]

How I can disable them? I would like to open my laptop and see clean screen.

**EDIT**

Screenshot from bach

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop the Adobe Creative Cloud app from auto-launching on login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138941/how-do-i-stop-the-adobe-creative-cloud-app-from-auto-launching-on-login)

Comment: I’m not comfortable merging this onto the older question and the dialog “Reopen windows” is responsible for most Apple apps relaunching.  This is really an example of a two parted question. Not all apps persist saved state in the same manner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Having re-read the question, my original answer may not be necessary. By default, when you log in, OS X opens all the windows you had open when you logged out. If you don't want it to do this, then uncheck the option "reopen windows when logging back in" that appears when you log out:

[image]

This *should* give you an empty desktop when you log back in. If not, then it's back to my original answer (below).

---

Some apps unfortunately don't respect that option, and create Launch Agents (processes that run at login) or sometimes Launch Daemons (which run at boot) to manage their lifecycle.

Such apps often do have a preference buried somewhere to change their login behaviour, so double-check that first, as that's always the safest solution.

If there isn't a preference, you can see what Launch Agents are running by going to your terminal and running:

`launchctl list`

If you want to see which Adobe-related agents are running, pipe the output to grep with something like:

`launchctl list | grep -i adobe`

If you see anything there, then it's likely that Adobe is using this mechanism. So what to do about it?

Have a look in the following folders to find files with the same names that you saw in the output of the `launchctl` command... in your case, probably called `com.adobe.<something>`.

- ~/Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/LaunchDaemons
- /System/Library/LaunchAgents
- /System/Library/LaunchDaemons

Once you've found them, try renaming rather than deleting them (e.g. by adding ".ignore" to the end of their filenames). Then reboot to see if that's had the desired effect. If it has, you're good to go... but watch out for other side-effects in case the Launch Agent has more than one function, and be prepared to go through the process again whenever you receive a software update.

If it hasn't worked, restore their original filenames to avoid any undesired side-effects, and keep digging...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand exactly first part of your answer `Such apps often do have a preference buried somewhere to change their login behaviour, so double-check that first, as that's always the safest solution.` - where I need to check? I am rookie in mac use)

Comment: and I have tried commands that you advised , but bash said that `couldn't find` screenshot attached

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Sorry, there was a typo in my answer-- the command to run in terminal should be 'launchctl'. I've edited to fix.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Also, I've re-read your original question and realised that there may be a simpler answer, which I've also just edited to mention.

Comment: yes, it is look like correct answer. Could you please help me with `creative cloud`. Now windows is not opened , but creative cloud still open every time... What is it creative cloud? Maybe I need to delete it? Or how I can turn it off? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

have a look in /Library/LaunchDaemons too.

Comment: Please edit scottishwildcat 's answer or make a comment if you don't want to write a full-fledged answer.