# Ways to make Big Sur run faster?

Tags: performance, big-sur

Some users report [Chrome and Firefox](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/k0abtt/firefox_and_chrome_painfully_slow_in_big_sur/) being slower on Big Sur

> On a 2019 MBP 13 (16GB) ... everything is noticeably slower ... even native apps like Preview

This reflects my experience.

Other than waiting for updates to Big Sur, what settings can I adjust in the mean time to help mitigate any jankiness Big Sur introduces?

Some solutions/ideas found so far:

- [Downgrade](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/downgrade-macos-3581872/) to older macOS versions

References:

- Google search for [big sur stuttery](https://www.google.com/search?q=big+sur+stuttery)

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't know which other settings could cause it, but I know that Chrome is notoriously bad CPU/GPU hog on all my Macs and avoid it like the plague. If I have to use another web browser other than Safari, I'd use Microsoft Edge myself, but that's a personal choice. Other than that, the usual recommendation is to hold off updating immediately to Big Sur and let the bugs be ironed out in updates. That said, I did update my late-2013 MacBook Pro 15" with Big Sur and for me it's run very smoothly so far. So I think performance may very mac to mac and hope that a future update may fix your issue

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

This is embarrassing but I now think Big Sur wasn't responsible for the choppiness on my machine at all. I had installed Adobe Creative Cloud shortly after updating to Big Sur. When I [uninstalled Adobe Creative Cloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/138945/290197) 7 days ago the choppiness completely vanished.

#### Previous answer

This is not an answer, but may help someone else. For about 3-4 days after updating to Big Sur, the cursor lurched across the screen, keyboard inputs took hundreds of milliseconds to appear on the screen (meaning I'd sometimes hit the key twice because I thought the first didn't register).

Approximately 4-7 days after the update, the behaviour disappeared entirely. I have not been able to explain **why** it happened (it never happened in Catalina, and it started immediately after updating to Big Sur, so I *presume* the update had something to do with it). And I also cannot explain **why** it stopped, except that it ceased 4-7 days after the update to Big Sur, without me doing anything.

Comment: How irritiating.When “everything” is slow, it’s so hard to nail down one thing to measure / profile/ test. This is absolutely an answer. Sharing will help us all corner things like this and we can always edit / improve as we learn more.

Comment: It turns out the lagginess went away for a while, but returned. I noticed [there's a lot of chatter in other forums](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/jzk8ya/macos_very_slow_after_big_sur_2019_macbook/). Hopefully it's resolved in the next update.

Comment: Oh no - might you be keeping logs of when it starts and stops and starts again?

Comment: @bmike only anecdotally. I found some more tips [here](https://piunikaweb.com/2020/12/04/macos-big-sur-update-choppy-animations-and-system-lag/) - I'll try when I get a chance and report back. I was hoping Big Sur 11.1 would include a fix, but it's actually a lot worse. Day to day work like text editing and web browsing is still very choppy.

Comment: I'm still in the throes of this problem, but I recently [stopped adobe creative cloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/138945/290197) starting automatically, so I will give it some time and see if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Randomly, I came across someone talking about [Adobe software slowing their computer down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKxyHAB948s&t=3715) (unclear whether they use a mac or something else). They recommended [PhotoPea](https://www.photopea.com/) instead because you don't need to install it (runs in the browser), and therefore doesn't have background processes running on / slowing down your local machine.