# How to see which services were unloaded using "launchctl unload -w" on macOS?

Tags: macos, launchd

I ran the following to disable Adobe background services.

```sh
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX="com.adobe"
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/{LaunchAgents,LaunchDaemons}/$BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX*.plist
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/$BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PREFIX*.plist
```

According to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356217/323825) answer, using `launchctl unload -w` adds services to override database.

The override database is obscure. How can I see which services were unloaded using "launchctl unload -w" on macOS?